Blank page after including an SVG file into an EPUB
I'm currently creating an e-book and have gotten the advice to put my illustrations in the SVG format since they are fairy simple. Unfortunately, doing that creates a blank page after a page that contains the illustrations no matter their size or margins. This only happens on smaller screens. Before using SVGs, this wasn't a problem.
I tried changing the width of an SVG to 0% and removing its margins. That didn't help. Removing its "float" helped, but the problem came back once I applied margin: 0 auto; to it.
Here's an example of my XHTML code:
<aside class="illustration">
    <object data="leaf.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
      <img src="leaf.png" alt="an illustration of a fallen leaf" />
    </object>
  </aside>

And this is the corresponding CSS:
.illustration {
  
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  page-break-before: avoid !important;
  
  }

Is there a way for me to include SVG illustrations without blank pages appearing after I do so?
Thank you

Most importantly: you shouldn't use SVG if your illustrations are not vector based – you should also prefer HI-Res raster images if your images contain highly complex vector data. What happens if you place the SVG via <img>  tag? You should also make sure the SVG has explicit width and height attributes as well as a namespace attribute xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" - epub readers usually have rather limited svg support (or at least not remotely on par with browsers).

@herrstrietzel Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry it's taken me so long to respond. My illustrations are vector based and are fairly simple so the format is perfect. If I use the <img> tag I can't include a fallback and the illustration isn't as high quality. Adding the width and height worked but I was unable to scale it for all screens past a certain point. Instead, After a few more hours, I figured out the page was there because of the x-overflow due to the illustration's margins. By adding overflow-x: hidden; the problem was solved

I see. Please consider to post your insights as an answer so it can help others struggling with similar problems. You mentioned the illustrations margins. You may also try to optimize the viewBox attribute to crop the svg image to its visible content
